# Mocha root level before is being called for plain typescript Function and throws error as "ReferenceError: before is not defined"

Tags: node.js, automation, mocha.js

I have folder structure for my tests where also I have some helper files which we call independently through command line

```
src
 > helper.ts
 > appconfigFile.ts
 > tests
     bootstrap.test.ts (which has root level hook before)
     testcase1.test.ts
```

When we call helper.ts file which is plain typescript function it throws error

```
"ReferenceError: before is not defined"
```

command we call - ts-node src/helper.ts

bootstrap.test.ts and helper.ts both call setConfig function which is in another file.

bootstrap.ts

```
   before(function() {
         setConfig(env);
     }
```

helper.ts

```
setConfig(env);
```

appConfigFile.ts

```
export function setConfig(env: string) {
  if (isInstantiated) {
    console.log('set', env);
    return;
  }
  console.log('set', env);
  currentEnv = env;

  AppConfig = require('./appConfig.test.json');

  isInstantiated = true;
}
```

Whenever I call this setConfig in my helper file it calls before function from bootstrap and I get error

```
before(function() {
^
ReferenceError: before is not defined
```

I am not getting why before function is being called for plain typescript function and its not a mocha test